# Отражение фонового изображения header'a

Tags: css3, html5

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, как добавить данное отражение, которое на картинке? Дело в том, что это отражение исходит из изображения header'a в начало content'a. Как это можно реализовать?

[image: фонового]

Comment: покажите пожалуйста исходник картинки, (сайт где представлен пример) велика вероятность что то что вы хотите сделать, есть просто картинка

Comment: @Broouzer King, скорее всего это не сайт, а макет, так как эти дублированные заголовки уже обсуждались здесь пару дней назад.

Comment: Судя по линиям, это не "отражение", а продолжение картинки с сильной прозрачностью, никаких заморочек, просто из макета это вырежьте, приклейте снизу png'шкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое отражение наиболее просто и, что самое важное, наиболее кроссбраузерно можно сделать картинкой, поставив ее на фон другого элемента.

**Вариант #1**:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 50vh;
  background: url(http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/dont_breathe_2016_horror_movie_17475.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}

.section {
  height: 50vh;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Nbq.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

---

**Вариант #2**:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/dont_breathe_2016_horror_movie_17475.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}

.header:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Nbq.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

.section {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как например:

```css
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section {
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs194-26/fa16/upload/files/proj4/cs194-26-adl/images/landscape5.jpg) bottom no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.section:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: url(https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs194-26/fa16/upload/files/proj4/cs194-26-adl/images/landscape5.jpg) bottom no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  box-shadow: inset 0px -25px 25px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```css
.image-block {
background:url(https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/930/Coast_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Waves_USA_Ocean_Kaneohe_521540_1280x775.jpg);
box-shadow:0 -40px 20px -20px white inset;
height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-block"></div>
```